# Why is this Windows 10 Settings app not showing any data (just label text)?

Tags: windows-10, control-panel

Background: for a favour, I'm helping out someone's HP desktop originally bought in 2010 running Windows 7 which has since been updated to Windows 10 (22H2 19045.3570), it still has HP's original OEM crapware from 2010 (which has somehow auto-updated to HP's 2020s-era bollocks, but anyway...).

I'm remotely connected via Splashtop, and the Windows 10 Settings App *appears* to load okay, but many of the areas don't show any data/values/images - instead they're all blank and only a few text labels are visible:

| **Settings > System > About**: | **User > Sign-in options** |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Some pages, like **User > Sign-in options** shows a message that Group Policy is being applied, but this machine is standalone and isn't part of an Active Directory domain.

Clicking the "Copy" buttons doesn't do anything: the clipboard content isn't modified at all.

While the **Personalization > Background** and **Colors** pages are unusable:

| Background | Colors |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

---

Oblig:

- **Yes**, I ran `sfc /scannow` and it only reported modified NTFS directory permissions ACLs.
- **Yes**, I also ran `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, and but it didn't report anything amiss as far as I can tell.
- **Yes**, most of the most-recent Windows Updates are applied, except for the updates that were released today (as today is Patch Tuesday).
- **No**, there no relevant entries logged to the *Application* nor *System* event logs after rebooting (only the usual errors about DCOM registration and *Windows Hello for Business* that seem to happen on every Windows 10 machine).

Searching online for things like "Windows 10 settings blank" or "Windows 10 settings pages no data shown" or "Windows 10 settings glitch" returns zero relevant results.

Initially I thought this might be some glitch due to the machine's *Intel HD Graphics*, or maybe a consequence of something Splashtop is doing, but the graphics drivers and hardware all seem fine elsewhere, so I'm stumped.

---

Another curious thing is that UWP applications (like the "new" Calculator app, or the Windows Security app, are shown with "native" Windows titlebars *outside* the UWP window area - I've never seen this before:

[image]

---

And for some reason, the "Run as Administrator" menu-item in File Explorer and the Start Menu doesn't work - I need to use `powershell "start cmd -v runAs"`.

---

For all the things that are *immediately broken* with this machine, it's disenhearting that `dism` and `sfc` report finding *nothing wrong* as far as they're concerned.

Comment: Can you create or log in as a new user profile on the machine and see if that changes anything? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-or-remove-accounts-on-your-pc-104dc19f-6430-4b49-6a2b-e4dbd1dcdf32 if dism and sfc don't work it could be some kind of weirdly corrupt profile.

Comment: @Mokubai I'm not able to do that right now for fear of losing my access via Splashtop

Comment: The good news is that Win 10 EOL is less than a year away. It might be time for the user to consider another OS, installed *de novo*. Unlikely the PC can run Windows 11, so a Linux distro might be a good choice. The user can test alternative from a live USB.